# Stop SVG group event propagation

Tags: javascript, svg, typescript

i have a svg group tag to which im assignig an event listener mouseover. The problem is that the event is propaging to all of his child and gets fire on over each child. I want the event to start only over the entire group.

```
<g class="courseStop" id="c-0-0">
    <path class="st5 spot2" d="M125.3,74.9c-2.2,0-4-1.8-4-4s1.8-3.9,4-3.9s3.9,1.8,3.9,3.9C129.3,73.1,127.5,74.9,125.3,74.9z"/>
    <path class="st6 spot" d="M125.3,67.7c1.8,0,3.2,1.4,3.2,3.2c0,1.8-1.4,3.2-3.2,3.2s-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.2C122.1,69.1,123.6,67.7,125.3,67.7
    M125.3,66.2c-2.6,0-4.7,2.1-4.7,4.7s2.1,4.7,4.7,4.7s4.7-2.1,4.7-4.7C130,68.3,127.9,66.2,125.3,66.2L125.3,66.2z"/>
</g>
```

i have many `.courseStop` and for each one i assign an event listener.

```
courseStops[j].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){                    
     app.selectTooltip('.c-'+j);
})
```

the problem is that the event starts when mouse is over each `<path>` and not over the entire group `<g>`

Answer (score 1):

The pointer event is not propagating down, it is bubbling up.

According to SVG 1.1, pointer events are only raised if the pointer is over a [graphics element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement), which `<g>` is not. The `mouseover` will only ever be raised if the pointer is over one of the contained paths or other graphics elements that take part in the group, and then bubbles up. Nonetheless, the [`pointer-events`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property gives you some control over what region exactly is considered for hit-testing.

[SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/interact.html#PointerEventsProp) adds a `pointer-events: bounding-box` value. That would theoretically give you the opportunity to raise events over the bounding box of the group as a whole, but it is new in SVG 2 and not yet implemented everywhere (Chrome: yes, Firefox: no. I am not able to locate a complete compatibility list).

If that does not meet your requirements where an event should be raised, you'll need to add an invisible grafics element (for example a `<rect>` with `style="fill:none;pointer-events:fill"`) to the group to trigger it there.

Comment: I want to improve your answer with this: https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleCem/98ut4jac/